# Is there a way I can close a file? fclose does not work well

Tags: c++, windows

I working on a WinApi project that the user upload the file he wants to encrypt and then I'm writing data to this file.

So, everything works well, but when I'm editing the file and encrypting it, the file is still "open" in the background. I'm using `fclose()` but it still does not stop the file from being used in the background. When the file is open I can't remove it.

Here is my code:

```
void write_file_to_encrypt(char* path1)
{
    srand(time(0));

    int x = rand() % 34234;

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(path1, "w");

    int _size = x;
    char* data = new char[_size + 1];

    if (fopen(path1, "w")) {
        GetWindowText(filechoosed, data, _size + 1);

        fwrite(data, _size + 1, 1, file);

        fclose(file);
    }

    return;
}

// Save
void save_file_to_encrypt(HWND hWnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;

    char file_name[100];

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = 100;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "All Files\0*.*\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;

    GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

    write_file_to_encrypt(ofn.lpstrFile);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file = fopen(path1, "w");
...
if (fopen(path1, "w")) {
```

You're calling `fopen()` twice. Change the `if` statement to:

```
if (file) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed "if" condition and changed place of fclose().

```
void write_file_to_encrypt(char* path1)
{
    srand(time(0));

    int x = rand() % 34234;

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(path1, "w");

    int _size = x;
    char* data = new char[_size + 1];

    if (file != NULL) {
        GetWindowText(filechoosed, data, _size + 1);

        fwrite(data, _size + 1, 1, file);

    }
    fclose(file);

    return;
}
```

Comment: There was no need to move the `fclose()`, it was already in the correct place. You should not call `fclose()` with a NULL pointer. Move it back inside the `if` block where it belongs